# Parse html paragraph with php, break into individual tags with their content and styling

Tags: php, html, dom

I'm trying to parse a single html paragraph into array of its building blocks - I have this html paragraph:

```
$element_content = '<p>Start of paragraph - <strong><em>This note</em></strong> provides <em>information</em> about the contractual terms.</p>';
```

What I did so far is this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($element_content);

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('*') as $node) {

    echo $node->getNodePath().'<br>';
    echo $node->nodeValue.'<br>';
}
```

Which gives me this result:

```
/p
Start of paragraph - This note provides information about the contractual terms.
/p/strong
This note
/p/strong/em
This note
/p/em
information
```

But I'd like to achieve this:

```
/p
Start of paragraph - 
/p/strong/em
This note
/p
 provides 
/p/em
information
/p
 about the contractual terms.
```

Any ideas on how to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in a DOM is a node. Not just the elements, but the text is, too. You're fetching the element nodes, but your result outputs the text nodes separately. So you need to fetch the DOM text nodes that are not just whitespace nodes. It is not difficult with an Xpath expression:

```
//text()[normalize-space(.) != ""]
```

`//text()` fetches any text node in the document (this includes CDATA sections). `normalize-space()` is an Xpath function that reduces a the whitespace groups inside a string to single spaces. Leading and trailing whitespaces will be deleted. So `[normalize-space(.) != ""]` removes all nodes from the list that contain only whitespaces.

The parent node of each text node is its element. Put together:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($content);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$nodes = $xpath->evaluate('//text()[normalize-space(.) != ""]');

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    echo $node->parentNode->getNodePath(), "\n";
    echo $node->textContent, "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
/p 
Start of paragraph - 
/p/strong/em
This note 
/p 
 provides 
/p/em 
information 
/p 
 about the contractual terms.
```

Comment: You Sir are a Genius! Works like a charm, thanks a million. I just had to remove the [normalize-space(.) != ""] part because it was merging some words together. Cheers!